# Colors available in LaTeX

Tags: color

```latex
\pagecolor{brown!20!}
\pagecolor{brown!20!, red!40!}
```

Normally colors are defined as in the code above or a combination of two colors can be shown separating with a comma.

Is there any documentation showing the variety of colors which can be used with above code eg red brown blue etc.?

Is there a way to code colors with RGB, for example 255, 190, 180?

Comment: Have a look at the `xcolor` documentation: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf

Comment: check the documentation of the xcolor package.

Comment: that is good--can i add another question--how do I add speckles to the base color to make it spotted/ as if another paint has been thrown on the base color